# Azure Data Factory AWS PostgreSQL RDS as source connection

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, azure-data-factory

I am attempting to use an AWS PostgreSQL RDS instance as my source for a data factory pipeline.  I am unable to get this connection to work in ADF v1 or v2.  I have tried everything from using a PostgreSQL connection to an Azure database for PostgreSQL.  Essentially I am going cloud to cloud, and this connection doesn't seem to be supported yet.  Has anyone else had any luck doing this?

Comment: I should add that I can successfully connect to my AWS PostgreSQL instance using an ODBC driver, using pgAdmin4, and other ways.  But trying using ADF is proving not possible.

Comment: can you post your error message from postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this is horribly broken as you have found out. Two main problems:

1) You must install the NpgSQL 2.0.14.3. driver (chose core installation option to ensure both x86 and x64 versions are installed)  this version won't validate the server certificate

2) PostgreSQL connector can only enter connection information using by uploading via PowerShell the current GUI does not support the full configuration of the data source:

Here is the example json:

```
{
    "name": "PostgreSqlLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "type": "PostgreSql",
        "typeProperties": {
            "server": "<server>",
            "database": "<database>",
            "username": "<username>",
            "password": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "<password>"
            }
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "<name of Integration Runtime>",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

alternatively, the ODBC driver can work around this issue as you need to specify additional properties on the connection string that are not exposed by the pg connector. you need to add the following value to the DSN:
**`sslmode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true`*

and that should resolve the error

*note:* the ODBC nor the Postgresql Connector's currently work with the ADF v2 Lookup activity.

Comment: It appears this json is for an on-prem PostgreSQL connection where I am trying to connect to one in AWS which shouldn't need an integration runtime.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes I believe you will still need an IR but I think you can use the default hosted in azure.

Comment: I started from scratch and I believe I'm closer. In V2 I created a "self-hosted" IR.  Created a connection of "PostgreSql" type.  Assigned the connection to the created "self-hosted" IR.  Edited the JSON in the advanced field to replicate what you have above.  Then I test connection and get: UserError: 'Type=Microsoft.Data.Mashup.MashupValueException,Message=PostgreSQL: We were unable to find a database provider with invariant name &apos;Npgsql&apos;.
This error could&apos;ve been the result of provider-specific client software being required&#44; but missing on this computer.

Comment: I tried to connect using the integration runtime configuration manager Diagnostics and get the same exact error.  Failed to connect to the database. Error message: PostgreSQL: We were unable to find a database provider with invariant name 'Npgsql'.
This error could've been the result of provider-specific client software being required, but missing on this computer.  To download client software for this provider, visit the following site and choose the 64-bit (x64) version of, at minimum, 'Npgsql version 2.0.12': https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=282716

Comment: You need to download and install the npgsql driver make sure you select gac install option

Comment: One step closer:  Failed to connect to the database. Error message: An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Npgsql.Tls.ClientAlertException: CertificateUnknown: Server certificate was not accepted. Chain status: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

Comment: I wasn't sure how or where to add "sslmode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true" so I just downloaded AWS's cert here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL and imported it into my trusted root certification authorities and to my surprise....everything magically works.  Well, I can connect via the IR Diagnostic tool.  Now to try creating a pipeline again....thanks!

Comment: Holy god it works.  Thank you for getting me in the right direction!

Comment: @CodeMonkey I've updated the article could you please mark this as the answer.  Glad to have helped

Comment: @CodeMonkey Could you explain with more details what do I need to do with the certificate? I've downloaded it, what do I need to do now? I need to import the certificate into the operating system of my local machine? Obs.: I also want to use Azure Data Factory AWS PostgreSQL RDS as a source connection.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I am using Azure Data Factory v2

Comment: @renan-v-novas Just seeing this now, sorry for the lack of response.  I had to install the cert on the OS that the IR was on along with ODBC and Npgsql drivers.

Comment: @CodeMonkey how did you get this working? Did you create a resource on Azure for the integration runtime? And is that where you installed the npgsql driver?

Comment: @simplycoding yes, it's been a few years since I set this up, but I had an IR installed on-prem and then installed the Npgsql .Net Provider and the PostgreSQL ODBC driver.

Comment: Got it, that makes a lot more sense. And obviously, that on-prem machine is running 24/7 right? Any issues with using it as an IR? Is it running Windows?

Comment: @simplycoding it's running 24/7 and haven't had any issues besides having to upgrade the postgresql drivers on occasion. No issues with the IR.